# Flex - Filtering an AdvancedDataGrid with Hierarchical Data

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, filter, hierarchical-data, advanceddatagrid

I am displaying project planning Tasks in a Flex application which I am developing and I am trying to filter the items displayed in the AdvancedDataGrid (ADG) so that only Tasks which start later than a user selected date are displayed.

Here is a VoTask class:

```
    public class VoTask {

    public var taskId:int;
    public var taskProjectId:int;
    public var taskParentId:int;
    public var taskName:String;
    public var taskStartDate:Date;
    public var taskEndDate:Date;
    public var taskType:String;
    public var taskStatus:String;
    public var children:/*Task*/Array;

    // Constructor.
    public function VoTask() {
    }
}
```

Most Tasks are children of parent summary Tasks and this hierarchical structure can be about 5 deep.

In my Model a flat array of Task data, from a SQL database, are put into an ArrayCollection as a collection of strongly typed Task objects called `tasksFlat`.

To prepare the data for displaying as a hierarchy I have a function which iterates through the `tasksFlat` ArrayCollection and, using the taskParentId, places each Task into the appropriate 'children' property of its parent. This provides me with a `tasksHierarchical` ArrayCollection containing a single top level parent Task and all of the remaining Tasks hierarchically organised as children within this.

My AdvancedDataGrid currently looks like this:

```
<mx:AdvancedDataGrid
        id="myADG"
        displayItemsExpanded="false"
        horizontalScrollPolicy="auto"
        headerStyleName="adgHeaderStyle"
        creationComplete="{presenter.onTasksAdvancedDataGridCreationComplete(event)}"
        width="100%" height="100%">

<mx:dataProvider>
    <mx:HierarchicalData source="{presenter.tasksHierarchical}" childrenField="children"/>
</mx:dataProvider>

    <mx:columns>
        <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn id="nameAdvancedDataGridColumn" dataField="taskName" headerText="Task" width="650"/>
        <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="taskStatus" headerText="Status" width="72"/>
        <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn id="startDateAdvancedDataGridColumn" dataField="taskStartDate" headerText="Start" width="160"/>
        <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn id="endDateAdvancedDataGridColumn" dataField="taskEndDate" headerText="End" width="160"/>
        <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn headerText="" width="64"/>
    </mx:columns>

    <mx:rendererProviders>

        <mx:AdvancedDataGridRendererProvider
                column="{startDateAdvancedDataGridColumn}"
                renderer="itemRenderers.TaskStartDate_ItemRenderer"/>

        <mx:AdvancedDataGridRendererProvider
                column="{endDateAdvancedDataGridColumn}"
                renderer="itemRenderers.TaskEndDate_ItemRenderer"/>

    </mx:rendererProviders>

</mx:AdvancedDataGrid>
```

The user interface includes a DateChooser. Currently when the date changes I apply a filterFunction (in my Presenter) as follows:

```
private function onSelectedDateChanged(event:Event):void {

    // Set the filterFunction for the tasks data.
    tasksHierarchical.filterFunction = tasksFilterFunction;

    // Refresh the tasks AdvancedDataGrid data source.
    tasksHierarchical.refresh();

}

private function tasksFilterFunction(obj:Object):Boolean{

    //the logic to decide if an element needs to be shown or not.
    var _task:VoTask = VoTask(obj);
    var _returnValue:Boolean;

    if (_task.taskEndDate < model.selectedDate) {
        _returnValue = false;
    } else {
        _returnValue = true;
    }

    return _returnValue;
}
```

On debugging I find that only the top level parent Task is responding to the filter function.

There are approximately 4000 tasks for the user to explore and I am concerned that if I have to iterate through all of the children to apply the filter function the performance will be poor. Can I filter only the items being displayed?

Perhaps I am going about this the wrong way, any guidance would be very welcome.

Thanks

Comment: Hi , I have hit the same requirement as you. Could you share how you implemented hirearchial rows in ADG with filters on column? Appreciate if you could help me out.

Answer (score 0):

When you apply filtering to an `ArrayCollection` it always gets applied on the first level. In your case you either need to apply the filtering recursively or you can override`HierarchicalData.getChildren(node:Object):Object` which will give you access to filter the first level children, along with the ability to call a filtered method for sub-children to any n-th level.

```
Class MyCollection extends HierarchicalData
{
  override public function getChildren(node:Object):Object 
  {
    if (node is a VoTask )
        (node.children as ArrayCollection).filterFunction = tasksFilterFunction;
        node.children.refresh();
    else if (node is a Task)
        (node.children as ArrayCollection).filterFunction = tasksFilterFunction;
        node.children.refresh();
    // You can also write a more complex process of filtering.

    return node;
  }
}
```